# the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document vs 2013 javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

This is an MVC5 related issue.

I cannot debug my javascript codes but I can debug my C# codes, it's so annoying, I read many solutions but none of them worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another team member added this and I wasn't aware of that.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = ture;
```

When you activate the EnableOptimizations, Visual Studio uses the .min version of .js files and you won't be able to debug them. I just changed it to false and it worked.